# What characters should I exclude when searching oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL statement is like this

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE clientname LIKE UPPER(?)
```

In Java code, I wrote

```
prepStatement.setObject(1,"%"+  userinput +"%")
```

I wonder how can I deal with special characters? Some characters, such as '%${}[],*', should they all be excluded or prevented from being used to search?

Comment: You can escape the special characters used in `LIKE` ('%' and '_'), if they appear in the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LIKE operator interprets any % or _ characters as wildcards, so if you want to stop it interpreting characters input by the user, you need to use an escape character, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE clientname LIKE UPPER(?) ESCAPE '/'
```

Then escape the user's input using something like (sorry, I'm not a Java guru so this might need some tweaking):

```
prepStatement.setObject(1,"%"+ userinput.ReplaceAll("%","/%").ReplaceAll("_","/_") +"%")
```

Comment: That's what I am trying to do and you gave me the exact answer.

Comment: One question: If I have multiple LIKE, where should I put "ESCAPE"? Next to each LIKE, or write one at the SQL statement end?

Comment: It's a clause for the LIKE operator, so you'll need to repeat it for each LIKE, e.g. `WHERE clientname LIKE UPPER(?) ESCAPE '/' OR clientaddress LIKE UPPER(?) ESCAPE '/'`.